# Need guideline for creating logs in php

Tags: php

First of all i apologize to post this question as i know this is not how to code website. But i am asking here after doing some searches but didn't get a satisfactory result.

Basically i need to know how can i make some sort of logs. I mean i have made users for my application structure is pretty simple

```
table 1 : userroles
id , role

table 2: users
id, username, passowrd, userroleid
```

i would like to know the process how to make some logs of each time each user logs in preferably in a separate file. Also, what changes should i make in my tables to achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `file_put_contents('file.log', 'Person logged in!', FILE_APPEND);` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new table

```
Table: Logs
date, user_id, action, additionalData
```

And when user make some action that need to be logged - just insert in this table.

For example - user is logged in:

```
$db->insert('logs', array(
     'date' => date(),
     'user_id' => $activeUserId,
     'action' => 'loggedIn',
     'additionalData' => json_encode(array(
          'userAgent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
     ))
));
```

**UPD:**
For another example you can log actions like logout or order created or any other you like.

Just change action and it will be new event

```
$db->insert('logs', array(
     'date' => date(),
     'user_id' => $activeUserId,
     'action' => 'orderPayed',
     'additionalData' => json_encode(array(
          'amount' => 10000000 // This this is enought :)
     ))
));
```

Additional Data is needed for storing additional data of the event. For example you can store in it order numbers or time that needed by user to perform this action.

Comment: what is the purpose of additionalData ?

Comment: by your code it is clear to me that userlogin can be logged but user actions how ?

Comment: I updated my answer. AdditionalData is not required here. I just describe very very very very simple dynamic logging system

Answer (score 0):

Please note that "logs" can be achieved in some way.

1) Like some large use third-party applications (Like forums) everything is stored inside the database even an eventual log.

2) You can use file, but if the file is putted inside the web directory every user that know the path can access to it (You can block this with some .htaccess rule).

This said you do not need to change the db to make a file log, you can put inside the log (raw text file) what you want. For starters i suggest you to read some tutorial about text file manipulation. Googling on it and you'll find plenty of those.

Comment: i have seen some tutorials and all of them are teaching about making a .txt file and writing to it... But what is the ideal standards ? I mean what approach experienced programmers use?

Comment: @Raheel http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.log.overview.html

Comment: It depends on how many people are using the application and if you want to track them with an application or reading the log. If you make the log onto the db than with some others application part you can access into it and (for example) filter the data. With logs you normally need to use it like a record saving.